# Multiple user sign up with django-allauth. Two signup forms not render

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-allauth

I am trying to implement two user types with allauth. I have read so many tutorials, documentations, and so on. Still can't render my custom two forms for registrations. When i add in settings ACCOUNT_FORMS = { 'signup': ...} which form to be used is ok. But for both is not rendered.

> Models.py

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser
from django.db import models

class User(AbstractUser):
    is_worker = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_company = models.BooleanField(default=False)

class Worker(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, 
primary_key=True)
    image = models.ImageField(default="default.jpg", 
upload_to='profile_pics')
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    phone = models.IntegerField()

    def __str__(self):
       return f'{self.user.username}'


class Company(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, 
primary_key=True)
    image = models.ImageField(default="default.jpg", 
upload_to='profile_pics')
    adrress = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    phone = models.IntegerField()

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.user.username}'
```

> forms.py

```
from . models import User, Worker, Company
from django import forms
from allauth.account.forms import SignupForm


class WorkerSignupForm(SignupForm):
    first_name = forms.CharField(label='First Name', max_length=50, 
required=True, strip=True)
    last_name = forms.CharField(label='Last Name', max_length=50, 
required=True, strip=True)
    phone = forms.CharField(label='Mobile phone', max_length=15, 
required=True, strip=True)
    def save(self, request):
    user = super(WorkerSignupForm, self).save(request)
    user.first_name = self.cleaned_data.get('first_name')
    user.last_name = self.cleaned_data.get('last_name')
    user.phone = self.cleaned_data.get('phone')
    user.is_worker = True
    user.save()
    return user

class CompanySignupForm(SignupForm):
    company_name = forms.CharField(label='Comapny name', 
max_length=100)
    adrress = forms.CharField(label='Adrress', max_length=250)
    phone = forms.CharField(label='Mobile phone', max_length=15)
    def save(self, request):
    user = super(CompanySignupForm, self).save(request)
    user.company_name = self.cleaned_data.get('company_name')
    user.adrress = self.cleaned_data.get('adrress')
    user.phone = self.cleaned_data.get('phone')
    user.is_company = True
    user.save()
    return user`
```

> Views.py

```
from . forms import WorkerSignupForm, CompanySignupForm
from allauth.account.views import SignupView

class WorkerSignUpView(SignupView):
    template_name = "customuser/worker_signup.html"
    form_class = WorkerSignupForm
    redirect_field_name = 'next'
    view_name = "worker_signup_view"
    success_url = None

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        kwargs['user_type'] = "is_worker"

worker_signup_view = WorkerSignUpView.as_view()

class CompanySignUpView(SignupView):
    template_name = "customuser/company_signup.html"
    form_class = CompanySignupForm
    redirect_field_name = 'next'
    view_name = "company_signup_view"
    success_url = None

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        kwargs['user_type'] = "is_company"

company_signup_view = CompanySignUpView.as_view()
```

> urls.py

```
from .views import worker_signup_view, company_signup_view



urlpatterns = [
    path("signup/worker/", view=worker_signup_view, 
name="worker_signup_view"),
    path("signup/company/", view=company_signup_view, 
name="company_signup_view"),
]
```

> worker_signup.html

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% load i18n %}

{% block head_title %}{% trans "Signup" %}{% endblock %}
{% block content %}
<h1>Worker</h1>
<h1>{% trans "Sign Up" %}</h1>

<p>{% blocktrans %}Already have an account? Then please <a href="{{ login_url }}">sign in</a>.{% endblocktrans %}</p>

<form class="worker_signup_form" id="worker_signup_form" method="post" action="{% url 'worker_signup_view' %}">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    {% if redirect_field_value %}
        <input type="hidden" name="{{ redirect_field_name }}" value="{{ redirect_field_value }}" />
    {% endif %}
    <button type="submit">{% trans "Sign Up" %} &raquo;</button>
</form>
{% endblock content %}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Correct get context data function

```
class CompanySignUpView(SignupView):
    template_name = "customuser/company_signup.html"
    form_class = CompanySignupForm
    redirect_field_name = 'next'
    view_name = "company_signup_view"
    success_url = None

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        ret = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        ret['user_type'] = "is_company"
        return ret

company_signup_view = CompanySignUpView.as_view()
```